# Do browser vendors optimize their browser against jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

Do browser vendors optimize against jQuery?

I know this sounds absurd anti-standard, but I can imagine browser vendor has optimization against jQuery code built into their JS compiler/interpreter.

For example, lets say the JS compiler/interpreter sees, $('.blah > p'), the browser can say, hmm, I see that user is trying to grab an element, instead of letting jQuery do all the browser detection, it could just take the [actual DOM object], and return $([actual DOM object]) right away.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that this happens?

Comment: What would they be saying if the optimized against just jQuery?  "Hey, use jQuery because anything else won't work as well."

Comment: @Sorpigal, I don't have any reason to believe this is happening. But I am afraid that it might, thus I am asking this question to anyone with better knowledge.

Comment: @Kevin628, this kind of thing happens quite often in other areas of the software development. For example, video card vendors actually create profiles for games so that games would run faster.

Comment: @voidvector I think what you're talking about is benchmarking.  In the benchmarking, the question that's asked is "How does our code run under popular products on the market?"  Optimizing for some particular product is a question more like, "How does our code run under X, and how can we make it run better for product X?"

Comment: The problem with this is that `$('.blah > p')` won't ever return a DOM object, it will return a jQuery object. So the browser would have to hook *back* into jQuery, which is dangerous because there's nothing stopping me (as a web developer) patching my own copy of jQuery but keeping the same version number. That's not something that happens in the video game industry I'd imagine?

Comment: The answer is NO. The proposition is absurd.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, sorry, but your comment is what absurd here. Many things started as external libraries and then received native implementation both for stadnartization and performance reasons. Doing on-the-fly replacement with native version is quite easy.

Comment: @Oleg, if I could understand your point, there's a chance I might change my mind.

Comment: "Free speed gain on calls used on majority of pages.", as already commented below.

Comment: It's the Jquery which needs to optimize itself for the browsers and not the vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No browser vendor announced such a feature at the moment.

It is possible, however. You can easily store for reference parsed Javascript (IL/bytecode, whatever you use in your engine) for most often used versions of jQuery inside JS engine and when incoming function matches that signature, replace it with native version.

I guess the only thing that you have to take in consideration is how much time you'd spend on implementing it vs. speed gains against modern JIT engines. Because some of them already compile code to some native form, at least partially, it is not quite clear if there will be any substantial gains or not.

Answer (score 4):

No guessing what `$` does would break any scripts that use `$` for different purposes. Consider a page [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/NqP2Y/) (this is actually a pretty weak example relative to what could be found in the wild, but I think it still demonstrates the difficulty well enough):

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
            How will the browser know to select this div with the selector '.bar .foo .bar', without actually running this script the way it is designed?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var x = $('.foo');
        console.log(x);
        console.log(x.selector) // '.bar .foo .bar'
    };
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = function(){
        return arguments[0];
    };
    $ = (function($){
        return function(selector){
            return jQuery('.bar ' + selector + ' ' + $('.bar'));
        }
    })($);
</script>
```

It would be beyond an optimization for the browser to know which div to select in advance. In fact the browser has to run the scripts the way it is designed to in order to select the correct div.

However many browsers to compile Javascript to a slightly lower level language such as Java or C++ code. Then if the browser downloads and caches jQuery once it will be cached it a compiled form on the users computer. This is not a `jQuery` specific optimization since it will happen with any cached script, but it is more significant of an optimization for large scripts like `jQuery`.

Comment: That's pretty easy to guard against from a browser vendor perspective, you can just check $().jquery once per page.

Comment: @voidvector: The browser can never know if it is actually jQuery. The existence of a `.jquery` property guarantees nothing.

Comment: Browser can easily detect known (even hard-coded) syntax tree of jQuery and replace it with native implementation. I'd do it. Free speed gain on calls used on majority of pages.

Comment: @voidvector Not that easily. `$` could refer to jQuery on and off referring to other things throughout a script. jQuery could also be extended with plug-ins on and off throughout the duration of a script. Browser's could break when jQuery releases an update. Browser vendors will only try to make optimizations that can't ever break Javascript. If you made a browser that someone could write valid Javascript for and that script wouldn't work on your browser, it's not the script that's broken, it's the browser.

Comment: @ascii-lime The actual implementation might be different. But I can see a number of ways to deterministically detect jQuery. For example, you can do a hash against the .js file of various jQuery versions, and check against that on page load.

Comment: @voidvector I added an example of why this is hard. It's not even clear immediately why that script should select only the one div matching '.bar .foo .bar', is it?

Comment: You don't need to guess anything. Native `JSON.parse` is faster not because browser "guess" anything in advance, but because it stores pointer to native function that gets called when you use `()`. It could be trickier with jQuery, as it often operates on things more complex than plain strings, but there is room for optimization there.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery Yet still, a browser that assumed `$` is always jQuery would be a broken browser.